# Preview a PDF inside your AIR application inside transparent and custom window

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a transparent windows (skinnable).
Inside, I'd like to preview some pdf file.
BUT, in the only a black screen appear, can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is to have a window with no tranparence option
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details. If you embed the respective component inside a standard window, does it show the PDF as expected?

Additionally, these links might be of interest:

- http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_do_I_display_a_PDF_file_in_an_AIR_desktop_appl-19323.html
- http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Preview_a_PDF_inside_your_AIR_application-10183.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an HTML component? If so, it's impossible to show PDF if your window is transparent. Here's the note from the Adobe documentation. I highlighted the interesting part. (source : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html)

> **Note**: When displayed in a transparent window, SWF content embedded in
>   an HTML page must be embedded using either the transparent or opaque
>   wmode. The default value for wmode is window, so if you do not specify
>   a value, SWF content may not be displayed. On Windows and Linux, SWF
>   content always appears on top of other content when wmode is set to
>   window or opaque. **PDF content cannot be displayed in a transparent
>   window no matter which wmode setting is used.**

You could show the PDF inside another window perhaps ? If you can't maybe you can find a way to open an invisible window, load the PDF there, draw it into a BitmapData oject then display the snapshot instead. Off course, this means no user interaction with the PDF whatsoever.

Comment: I made my test with html component, the result is black screen and I tested with uicomponent, the result is white screen. I'd like to do a file explorer with the same GUI (custom, transparent windows). Tnaks